# How is it possible that sub-setting on a part of a data set increases the MSE for Ordinary Least Square (OLS)?

Tags: regression, least-squares, mse

I am using OLS to predict price for a data set of cars. I have the following categorical features:

```
 ['ModelYear', 'Province', 'BodyType', 'Year', 'Month','TransmissionType', 'CarFuelType']
```

and only one non-categorical feature:

```
['Milage']
```

When I use OLS for the entire data set, I get the following results:

```
Test r^2 score:  0.884958272024
(normalized) Mean Sqr Error:  14787783.2542
AVG price:  172792220.37448004
STD price:  43601151.72460971
```

However, when I subset on the `ModelYear` (let say on 2016) I get the following results:

```
Test r^2 score:  0.0697490850982
(normalized) Mean Sqr Error:  16922600.0875
AVG Test price:  209564708.85093167
STD Test price:  17548958.668762047
```

As you see on the subset we have lower test variance, as is expected. However, MSE is increased and R^2 is decreased. This is the case for all other `ModelYears` as well.
How is this possible? 
My intuition is that on a smaller data set I should have better prediction.

I am standard scaling all the features including dummy variables for categorical features.

Comment: You probably know that as sample size increases, the variance of the OLS estimator decreases. That is not surprising: given more data we can estimate the model parameters with higher precision. So what is the puzzle?

Comment: Here it is not with higher precision, as the the data is increased. It is the other way around. The MSE is increased as the data has become smaller (second case).

Comment: Exactly. Less data --> higher MSE --> lower precision. More data --> lower MSE --> higher precision. Probably you misunderstood what MSE indicates: high MSE means low precision.

Comment: what is your dependent variable ?

Comment: I think something is misunderstood. Note that the data is subset on one feature, namely ModelYear. So I am considering all cars built in 2016, and since this is a categorical feature, cars built on other years should NOT influence the line fitted for each of them (since different coefficient is learnt for each year, using dummy variables). Also note that, as I said I have this increase in MSE when I subset on all years. Moreover the data is big enough to compensate for possible reduction.
@Richard

Comment: Price is my dependent variable. 
@subhash

Comment: How big the data is has nothing to do with the fact that the precision of the OLS estimator grows with the sample size; it happens both in small and large samples. What do you mean by *subset on all years* -- perhaps taking the full sample (no proper subset)? Also, if you wrote down your model, you could see more clearly whether or not cars built on other years influence the line fitted for each of them. But you have not written down the model for us.

Comment: by subset I mean taking the full sample: 
`X = df[(df['ModelYear'] ==  2016)`
But how could cars built in different years can influence each other, if I am using one-hot encoding? for a car built in 2016 only `ModelYear_2016 ` is 1 and the rest are 0.

Answer (score 0):

What is the difference between 'Model Year' and 'Year'?

Your intuition that a smaller data set has better prediction is wrong because predictive power of a model increases with more information in terms of both breadth (more variables) and breadth (number of observations).

R squared indicates the total amount of variation that is explained by each of your independent variables. Each independent variable can contribute differently towards explaining the variation in the dependent variable.

It is possible that 'Model Year' is a better predictor of price than the other variables, which led to a high R squared and low MSE. And that predictive power was lost when you removed the 'Model Year' variable, leading to a higher MSE in the subset model.

It is also possible that there are other variables that were not considered in your model that are important to predict price correctly.